# Zipping to a specific directory in python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, zip

I tried zipping a directory /tmp using the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import zipfile


def zipdir(path, zip):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w')
    zipdir('tmp/', zip)
    zip.close()
```

The output of the above code seems to create the zip file in "/" directory. Is there any way to re-direct the output to another directory, say, /home/zipfiles ?

Comment: Where are you running this from?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just set

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/home/zipfiles/whatever.zip', 'w')
```

What you have now will create the file in whatever directory you're running the script from.

Note: It'd probably be a good idea to pick a name that isn't `zip`. `zip` is a builtin, and it's always annoying to find that you're getting weird `TypeErrors` because you accidentally shadowed a builtin you needed.